# how banner view works?

Tags: iphone, ios

hello guys im just starting out at developing a  ios application and came across iAd, admob and such networks . i was wondering how do they open a banner(i think thats a view) above the core applications.if you could point me in a right direction it would be of much help

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right it is a view subclass.  It can be declared in your xib file or created programmatically.  Apple even has a view specifically for iAd.  You can "show" or "hide" the view based on if you have an ad to fill it.  You can also do all sorts of animations to slide it in.  There are several good tutorials out their that explain how to implement it.  Ray Wenderlich is always a good source...

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app

You can even create a view that shows AdMob ads in place of the iAd view if it's not filled.